# Toggle JTextField visibility

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've set a `JTextField` visibility to `false`, and when I click a button it is supposed to immediately show but it doesn't until I resize the window.

I'm building a login/'sign up' app using Swing containing tree text fields (Username, password and confirm password (which visibility is set to false until I press the signup button). But the text field does not appear until I resize the window and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I used the same 'code structure' as I did in another project, and didn't have any problem at all.

You can see the code below:

```
setTxtusername(new JTextField("Entrez username",20));
getTxtusername().setVisible(true);
setTxtpassword(new JTextField("Entrez Password",20));
getTxtpassword().setVisible(true);
setTxtconfirmer(new JTextField("Confirmer Password",20));
getTxtconfirmer().setVisible(false);
setBtnlogin(new JButton("Login"));
getBtnlogin().setVisible(true);
getBtnlogin().addActionListener(l);
getBtnlogin().setActionCommand("login");
setBtnsignup(new JButton("Sign up"));
getBtnsignup().setVisible(true);
getBtnsignup().addActionListener(l);
getBtnsignup().setActionCommand("Signup");

//Hb is an horizontal box and Vb is a vertical one      

getHb2().add(btnlogin);
getHb2().add(btnsignup);
getHb2().add(warninglabel);
getHb2().setVisible(true);
getVb().add(txtusername);
getVb().add(txtpassword);
getVb().add(txtconfirmer);
getVb().add(hb2);
getVb().setVisible(true);
pnl.add(vb);
pnl.setVisible(true);
```

Here is the `ActionListener`

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = e.getActionCommand().toString();
        switch(action){
        case "login":

            break;
        case "Signup":
            ConfirmerVisible(true, txtconfirmer);
            conteneur.revalidate();
            creationCompte();
            break;
        }
    }
    public void creationCompte() {
        if(getTxtconfirmer().getText().length() >=6 && getTxtpassword().getText() == getTxtconfirmer().getText()) {
            if(admin.isSelected()) {
                Utilisateur u = new Utilisateur(txtusername.getText(), getTxtpassword().getText(), 1);
                //Connexionuser.create(u);
                //Connexionuser.login(u)
            }
        }
    }

}
private void ConfirmerVisible(boolean b, Component c) {
    c.setVisible(b);
}
}
```

Comment: That is not an ActionListener.  An ActionListener is object that implements [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).

Comment: Don't cal `setVisible` on the parent window until the UI is established.  If the UI is already visible, call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container that's changed to trigger a new layout and paint pass

Comment: @MadProgrammer 'revalidate' worked ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @VGR i copy pasted the wrong lines of code, my action listener was : public class Listener implements ActionListener{
//Some code
}

Comment: 1) `setTxtpassword(new JTextField("Entrez Password",20));` Use a [`JPasswordField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) instead. It will require a separate `JLabel` to identify it, as a password field does not display the normal characters. 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, ..

Comment: .. `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1) It sure looks like a good idea 2) Can you tell me why it is better than the flowlayout ?  3) I will surely look into that. Thanks for your review, I really appreciate

Comment: Comparing FlowLayout to CardLayout is like comparing apples to oranges -- they're two completely different beasts and used for completely different things. That you're asking this suggests that you don't understand them at all, which is OK, unless you don't remedy this. You will want to read the tutorials on these layouts to understand what @AndrewThompson is suggesting

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I had a short class about GUI's in Java about 2 or 3 weeks ago and we didn't used them except for a very simple exercice. Do you have any suggestion for tutorials ?

Comment: Yes, Google "java cardlayout tutorial", same for FlowLayout. Google will bring them right to you

Comment: *"2) Can you tell me why it is better than the flowlayout ?"* It is not 'better' or 'worse' than flow layout just different, and used for different effects. I was suggesting to use a card layout for toggling the visibility of the component. The trick would be to use a panel with a card layout. Cards: 1) the component to be toggled 2) a blank panel. On button click, flip the cards from one to the other. Note that panel using the card layout might itself be put in a flow layout. The **difference** between card layout and toggling the visibility is that the space where the component was, would ..

Comment: .. be preserved in a flow layout, and the rest of the elements after it would not change position - which might be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh GUI Use:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

I guess once you doing "resize" it's triggered automatically by JFrame and recursively triggering refresh on child components also.